# InStr VBA differentiate between lower and upper character

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the following vba code to check if a password has an upper case letter

```
'See if there is an upper case
    For i = 65 To 90
        If (InStr(1, Me.Password, Chr(i))) Then
            hasUpper = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
```

But it looks like for a password like "asd12" has Upper is set to true because `A` is the same as `a`

Is there a way to use the Instr function so that it can differentiate between upper and lower characters?

Answer (score 2):

If this is just about upper-case characters, and you don't want to take on regex, an easy approach (which is somewhat suboptimal performance-wise, but a password check taking an extra millisecond probably won't hurt anyone) is checking if the lower-case string is equal to the string (in which case there won't be uppercase characters).

```
'See if there is an upper case
If StrComp(Me.Password, LCase(Me.Password), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then hasUpper = True
```